# Making a Rails backend for an Android/iOS chat app. Which websocket gem should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

Right now I'm considering websocket-rails, faye-websocket, em-websocket, or webmachine. Is there any benefit for one over the others?

Comment: try private_pub..http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub